# oracle sql 'Alter USER test_user2 GRANT CONNECT THROUGH test_user1 ROLE myTestRole1;' throwing 'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended' error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-grant, ora-00933

I'm executing the following sql
`Alter USER test_user2 GRANT CONNECT THROUGH test_user1 ROLE myTestRole1;`
in Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 database and running in to the following error:-

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
Alter USER test_user2 GRANT CONNECT THROUGH test_user1 ROLE myTestRole1
Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

getting `syntax error partially recognized rules railroad diagrams` prompt in the `ROLE` word.

when I checked the documentation the syntax was correct and I have all the grant, alter user, and GRANT CONNECT THROUGH permissions and both the users test_user1, test_user2 are created and the role myTestRole1 is also created.

Note:- this sql `Alter USER test_user2 GRANT CONNECT THROUGH test_user1` runs successfully.
can anyone please help me with this. Thanks!

Tried executing this sql Alter USER test_user2 GRANT CONNECT THROUGH test_user1 ROLE myTestRole1 and was not expecting a SQL command not properly ended error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 'with' missing before ROLE:
Alter USER test_user2 GRANT CONNECT THROUGH test_user1 with ROLE myTestRole1;